# Detecting which SIM a incoming call is coming from android?

Tags: java, android, call, incoming-call

I neeed to detect target sim card of incoming call on multiple sim devices. I have tired a lot of posts and tried many solutions, but all the solutions are outdated. Not working on newer version of Android.

I tried the below solutions, nothing helps

```
    int simSlot = intent.getIntExtra("simSlot", -1);
    int simId = intent.getIntExtra("simId", -1);
    int slot = intent.getIntExtra("slot", -1);
```

These all are `returns -1`

```
String[] array = new String[]{
        "extra_asus_dial_use_dualsim",
        "com.android.phone.extra.slot",
        "slot",
        "simslot",
        "sim_slot",
        "subscription",
        "Subscription",
        "phone",
        "com.android.phone.DialingMode",
        "simSlot",
        "slot_id",
        "simId",
        "simnum",
        "phone_type",
        "slotId",
        "slotIdx"
};

for (String item :
        array) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Sim Card - " + item + " -----> " + intent.getExtras().getInt(item));
}
```

The output is always `returns 0`

Some articles shows it's not possible. But TrueCaller shows the target simcard for all incomming calls in all android mobiles.

I want to know solution like this

**I tried so many ways nothing helps. Any help will be highly appriciated. Thanks in advance**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing this inside your BroadcastReceiver class,

```
    public class IncomingCallInterceptor extends BroadcastReceiver {
     @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String callingSIM = "";
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    callingSIM =String.valueOf(bundle.getInt("simId", -1));

    if(callingSIM == "0"){
        // Incoming call from SIM1
    }
    else if(callingSIM =="1"){
        // Incoming call from SIM2
    }
    }
```

Comment: did you clearly read my question bro

Comment: this is not working

Comment: My apologies. I hope you came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59831344/14577209) answer. However, the SIM card data could be retrieved from `TelecomManager` class according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71986007/14577209). But I doubt whether if it is real-time or after receiving the call. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: yes bro , by usin the method we can get it after receiving the call

Comment: can you help to solv the issue

Comment: I trapped almost 3 days

Comment: Did you try it out? Do you need it when the call is coming in real time? not after receiving the call?

Comment: yes bro , I need it on real time

Comment: like truecaller showing in the popup

Comment: It seems like it is not possible to make it work on all devices but depends on the android version. Which Android version are you trying out the solution for?

Comment: Im trying on android 11, 12,13 not works

Comment: but how true caller did

Comment: If you find any solution let me know bro

Comment: I will try to provide you another solution as a new answer. Give me sometime. Give it a try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253321/discussion-between-maleesha97-and-anand).

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following solution for this using `SubscriptionInfo` class.

- But this works only when the phone number is associated with the SIM card.

  ```
  TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
   SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager = SubscriptionManager.from(getApplicationContext());

   // Create a PhoneStateListener to detect incoming calls
   PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
       @Override
       public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String phoneNumber) {
           if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
               // Retrieve the list of active subscriptions
               List<SubscriptionInfo> subscriptionInfoList = subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
               if (subscriptionInfoList != null) {
                   // Loop through the list of active subscriptions
                   for (SubscriptionInfo subscriptionInfo : subscriptionInfoList) {
                       // Retrieve the phone number of the SIM card
                       String simPhoneNumber = telephonyManager.getLine1Number(subscriptionInfo.getSubscriptionId());
                       if (simPhoneNumber != null && simPhoneNumber.equals(phoneNumber)) {
                           // The incoming call belongs to this SIM card
                           int simSlotIndex = subscriptionInfo.getSimSlotIndex();
                           Log.d(TAG, "Incoming call belongs to SIM card in slot " + simSlotIndex);
                           break;
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   };
  ```

Register the PhoneStateListener,

```
telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Comment: bro this also not works is there any other way

Comment: this is not working on lattest versions

Comment: Nope. This is what I could find and implement. It should work on latest versions. It's highly depending on various factors such as Sim card association with the phone number, SIM cannot have multiple numbers and such.

Comment: Is there any way to find sim card serial number

Comment: Yes. its possible. you can use `telephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber();` to obtain it from above code. make sure you have READ_PHONE_STATE permission given first.

Comment: no it returns empty string

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76116926/5197712